# how can I calculate the cutoff frequency for this low pass filter?

Tags: low-pass, cutoff-frequency, damping-factor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4sYYH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Add a source to your circuit and click where it says "simulate this circuit".

Answer (score 1):

While there is not a compact analytic solution, some insight may derived from an [open circuit time constant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-circuit_time_constant_method).

In this method, we first compute the time constant associated with each capacitance:

$$
\tau_1 = 68 ~\text{pF} \cdot 0 = 0~s\\
\tau_2 = 2.2 ~\mu\text{F} \cdot \left(500\Omega || \left(5\text{k}\Omega+10\text{k}\Omega\right)\right) \approx 1.06~\text{ms} \\
\tau_3 = 100 ~\mu\text{F} \cdot \left(\left(500\Omega+5\text{k}\Omega\right)||10\text{k}\Omega\right) = 0.355~\text{s}
$$

The overall time constant is the sum of these values:

$$
\tau_{OCT} = \tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3 = 0.356~\text{s}
$$

The predicted -3dB frequency is therefore:

$$
f_{OCT} = \frac{1}{2\pi\tau_{OCT}} = 0.447~\text{Hz}
$$

This is within 0.2% of the value simulated in CircuitLab (0.446 Hz).  Note that -3dB frequency is almost entirely set by the time constant of C3.  In other words, there is a [dominant pole](http://homepages.wmich.edu/~kamman/ME360DominantPoles.pdf).

Comment: I think you just gave him the answer to a homework question. It probably would have been better to provide an explanation and formulas, but left actual numbers out of it